# Correct plural usage for "hundreds" and "thousands"

Tags: word-usage, plural-forms

I'm having problems with *hundred* and *thousand*.

If someone asks you, *How many trees are in this forest?* Would you answer *seven thousand* or *seven thousands*, because thousands are countable?

I know that you usually say *seven thousand*, but I also know that thousands are countable, so wouldn't that make it *seven thousands*?

And when you are talking about multiple countable nouns, you would make it plural, but the plural isn't *thousand*, it's *thousands*, so it couldn't be that *thousand* is the plural.

Why isn't it *a few thousands*? Is it because of an exception in English? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I would answer with one of these: (a) seven **thousand**; (b) a few **thousand**; (c) **thousands** of trees.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is because you are not counting the **thousands**, you are counting the **trees**.
So when you say:

> There are seven thousand trees.

The noun *trees* is countable and plural. *thousand* is an adjective in this example. Even if you don't say "trees" its still implied.

But you could say:

> There are *thousands* and *thousands* of trees."

where "thousand" is used as a noun and you are counting groups of 1,000.

Comment: The same is true even for a single _thousands_ reference; for example: _There are **thousands** of trees in this forest_. But that could also be stated as: _There are a few thousand trees in this forest._

Comment: Also, saying "seven thousands" implies that there are seven separate, distinct groups of one thousand trees, like the enumeration of armies in the middle ages i.e. "The King gathered his forces: the host assembling into ten thousands."